# React router bootstrap LinkContainer returns TypeError: (0 , _reactRouterDom.withRouter) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-bootstrap

It seems like since the recent update `React` had, everything related to the routing has been changed. I used to use `LinkContainer` from `react-router-bootstrap` but it's now throwing

```
TypeError: (0 , _reactRouterDom.withRouter) is not a function.
```

```
    import React from "react";
    import { Navbar, Container, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
    import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";
    
    function Navbarr() {
      return (
        <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
          <Container>
            <LinkContainer to="/">
              <Navbar.Brand>LOGO</Navbar.Brand>
            </LinkContainer>
            <Nav className="me-auto">
              <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          </Container>
        </Navbar>
      );
    }
    
    export default Navbarr;
```

What changes do I have to make to get it to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears react-router-bootstrap hasn't been updated in 3 years and is no longer compatible with react-router-dom@v6.  I bet if you rolled back your react-router-dom to version 5.2 it will work.

Another solution that worked for me instead of using LinkContainer you could also just use the "as" attribute for the Navbar.Brand and Nav.Link components with react-router-dom.

exemple:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

<Container>
     <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to='/'>LOGO</Navbar.Brand>
</Container>


export default Navbarr;
```

Comment: How do you reactify the Nav.Link since it takes href by default ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly but try to change the "href=" attribute to "to=" attribute and don't forget to add as={Link} to make the component to a link so it will look something like this
<Nav.Link as={Link} to="/home">Home</Nav.Link>